# Holding suited connectors odd of flopping 2 pair or better

Tags: probability, pre-flop

Pre flop with suited connector what are the odds of flopping 2 pair of better?

For example if I am facing a bet and a raise from big stacks and I have 78s what are my odds.  I am up against an over pair and or over cards.  I basically need 2 pair or better to win and I don't want to chase it to the river.  What are my chances of flopping 2 pair or better so I can put pot odds in perspective?

With 5 random cards the odds are [7.62%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability).

I see the pros play suited connectors pretty often. Trying to understand the math better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on figures from http://www.flopturnriver.com/poker-strategy/pyroxenes-common-flop-odds-19147, the odds of flopping 2 pair or better, not including draws, is just over 5.6%.

Including flopping a straight or flush draw, the odds are just a hair over 27%.

If your facing a raise and re-raise, you should probably fold, as you're not getting the right odds.

Generally you want to play suited connectors in late position or the blinds, especially when there are several callers, so that you're getting good odds.

Comment: Or deep stacked early in a tournament when the implied odds are there.

Answer (score 0):

Naturally the odd of trips, full house, and four of a kind goes down as you are not holding a pair.

I ran the number and here are the results I got:

- trips, full house, four of a kind
  1.44%
  0.63 x compared to a random hand
  odds go down by 1/3
- flush
  0.84%
  4.28 x compared to a random hand
- straight
  1.3%
  3.34 x compared to a random hand
- two pair
  2.02%
  0.43 x compared to a random hand
  (by eliminating a pair in your hand your odds of 2 pair is less)
- two pair or better
  **5.6% =  18.7 : 1**
  0.74 x compared to a random hand

Behind a single raise and single re-raise not getting odds unless you think you have chance to stack a big stack.

Favors a multiplayer (4+) pot with big stacks. Your chance of a dominant hand (straight or flush) goes up but you are still exposed to a boat or quads.

Add on top of that

- 10.94% chance of a 4 flush draw
- 10.42% chance of an 8 outer straight draw
- 21.37% total

The odds of getting suited connectors in your hand is 4% or 24.5:1.

Holding suited connectors the odds of getting a flush or straight by the river is 5.7:1

**Ran a simulation and this is want I got**

This excludes pair and trips on the board

```
hand Quads      count     2   pct 0.01
hand StrFlush   count     4   pct 0.02
hand Boat       count    18   pct 0.09
hand Flush      count   161   pct 0.82
hand Straight   count   252   pct 1.29
hand Trips      count   264   pct 1.35
hand TwoPair    count   396   pct 2.02    
hand OnePair    count 5,676   pct 28.96
hand HighCard   count 12,827  pct 65.44
TwoPairOrBetter pct 5.60    16.9:1   
flush draw           2,145  pct 10.94
straight draw 8 outs 1,530  pct  7.81
TwoPairOrBetter or 8+ outs  pct 24.35    3.1:1
straight flush draw 15 outs pct 1.15
```

Does anyone on this site know C# that is willing to review the code?

Getting 3.1:1 so with 2 others in the pot it is playable in position.
Out of position even play it with 3 others in the pot if betting is capped.

Answer (score 0):

Preflop with small suited connectors is a good play for the implied odds. 18 to 1 is ok 6 handed for $60 when you know the bet on the flip will be half the pot or more ($150-200+) if you hit or not.